# SnappyData submit a jar to cluster with parameters

Tags: snappydata

SnappyData documentation give an example on how to submit a jar to a cluster:

https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/howto/run_spark_job_inside_cluster/

But what if I need to submit the jar with the same class CreatePartitionedRowTable
multiple times, but with different paramter, say different suffix to append to the names of the tables created, How do I do that?

UPDATE:

To be more precise, say I want to submit the jar with different parameters when I submit the jar, something like this

```
bin/snappy-job.sh submit
    --app-name CreatePartitionedRowTable
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.snappydata.CreatePartitionedRowTable
    --app-jar examples/jars/quickstart.jar
    --lead localhost:8090
    --CustomeParam suffix
```

the additional

```
--CustomeParam suffix
```

will be passed in to the job, and the code can pick up this parameter suffix, and appending the suffix to the table names to be created, so that I don't have to modify my code every time that I want to submit the jar with a different suffix.

Update 2:

I just went through the examples and found an example usage:
https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/snappydata/CreateColumnTable.scala

so basically run like this:

```
 *   bin/snappy-job.sh submit
 *   --app-name CreateColumnTable
 *   --class org.apache.spark.examples.snappydata.CreateColumnTable
 *   --app-jar examples/jars/quickstart.jar
 *   --lead [leadHost:port]
 *   --conf data_resource_folder=../../quickstart/src/main/resources
```

and use config to get the customized parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you submit your app jar with snappy-job.sh it will create a new Job and run it. It could be the same jar with different content. Do you see any exception or the modified class (CreatePartitionedRowTable) is not getting picked ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand that submitting the jar multiple times will result in new jobs, please see my update in the question